# Indexing GIS data associated with user with timestamp

Tags: algorithm, spatial-index, spatio-temporal-data

I have data for each user in this format user1:(timestamp,lattitude,longitude) user1:(timestamp1,lattitude1,longitude1).....

Here the 1 at the end of timestamp/lat/long is to specify a different point in 3d space.

I want to have a indexing structure where I can associate a point in 3d space (spatio-temporal) with a user and be able to do nearest neighbour queries based on either spatial data or temporal data or both. Is there a good indexing scheme for something like this or an algorithm in literature to look at?

Comment: Practically speaking, I think you would do well to look into simply using an existing DBMS's spatial index as well as indexing the user and date/timestamp columns. Could you elaborate on your motivations?